Graph formula for $x\mapsto 2x$
To get a better grasp at graph formulas of computable functions I've been trying to represent $x\mapsto 2x$ in Peano Arithmetic, with no success. I want to write
$$\vdash G(x,y) \iff \Big[(x=0)\land (y=0)\Big] \lor \exists z\exists w\Big[(s(z) = x) \land (s(s(w)) = y) \land G(z,w)\Big]$$
yet it is not valid to write $G$ itself inside the formula.
